# why wont animationDrawable run after second click of button

Tags: android, multithreading, animationdrawable

hi everyone hope you can help and thanks for looking -

i have a thread to run a coin spinning animation which is this

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
static AnimationDrawable frameAnimation;

public boolean currentSpin = false;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //is this where you want me to do it
    ImageView coinAnima = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);


    Button bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
      bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        spinCoin1();
        }
    });

}
//end of onCreate

public void spinCoin1(){
    coinAnima = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    coinAnima.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.coin_spin_heads); 

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) coinAnima.getBackground();
                        frameAnimation.start();

                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(5000);
                          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                          }    

                          frameAnimation.stop();

                    //end of run
                    }

        //starts the thread        
         }).start();

//end of method      
}
//end of class
}
```

it runs from an onclick of a button, 
when i click the button a second time it causes and error

which is

```
    03-10 23:33:28.804: E/AndroidRuntime(13689): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-12
03-10 23:33:28.804: E/AndroidRuntime(13689): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
03-10 23:33:28.804: E/AndroidRuntime(13689):    at android.view.ViewRoot.checkThread(ViewRoot.java:2936)
03-10 23:33:28.804: E/AndroidRuntime(13689):    at android.view.ViewRoot.invalidateChild(ViewRoot.java:642)
03-10 23:33:28.804: E/AndroidRuntime(13689):    at android.view.ViewRoot.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRoot.java:668)
03-10 23:33:28.804: E/AndroidRuntime(13689):    at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:2511)
03-10 23:33:28.804: E/AndroidRuntime(13689):    at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:5272)
03-10 23:33:28.804: E/AndroidRuntime(13689):    at android.view.View.invalidateDrawable(View.java:7310)
03-10 23:33:28.804: E/AndroidRuntime(13689):    at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:176)
03-10 23:33:28.804: E/AndroidRuntime(13689):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:300)
03-10 23:33:28.804: E/AndroidRuntime(13689):    at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableContainer.selectDrawable(DrawableContainer.java:227)
03-10 23:33:28.804: E/AndroidRuntime(13689):    at android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable.setFrame(AnimationDrawable.java:211)
03-10 23:33:28.804: E/AndroidRuntime(13689):    at android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable.nextFrame(AnimationDrawable.java:203)
03-10 23:33:28.804: E/AndroidRuntime(13689):    at android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable.run(AnimationDrawable.java:140)
03-10 23:33:28.804: E/AndroidRuntime(13689):    at android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable.start(AnimationDrawable.java:107)
03-10 23:33:28.804: E/AndroidRuntime(13689):    at com.example.testanima.MainActivity$2.run(MainActivity.java:61)
03-10 23:33:28.804: E/AndroidRuntime(13689):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

can anyone tell me a fix for this error and thanks again for looking

Comment: Whats your exact requirement??

Comment: Try iniatiating the ImageView coinAnima in onCreate method.

Comment: @ kalyan id like to be able to restart the coin spin animation with a button press after it stops spinning...its part of an app...i need 2 coins to spin

Comment: @Atul sorry i havent been programming long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't maniuplate gui elements in another thread. This is clearly stated in the docs.

You can update gui elements in your run() by using:

```
 public void run()
 ...
  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            update gui elements
                        }
                 });
 ....
```

Also call clear() on your animation after your first animation has completed. Then you can use it more than once.

Comment: Sorry - I gave you bad info before regarding clear(). Use `View.clearAnimation()` and not `Animation.clear()` You can read here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html

Comment: I can't see that your code would work, you are still updating gui elements in another thread and not on the ui thread.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22301344/why-doesnt-second-animationdrawable-work is my 2 coin code if u like to have a look

Comment: hey i reposted my question about running 2 animation drawables at once if u like to look....it should be differant to the other Q's as they were about 1 spinning coin...but this one is about 2 spinnings coins at once codes identical and i thought they should just run at the same time when called together  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22322200/running-2-animationdrawables-at-the-same-time

Answer (score 0):

You could create your coinAnima on the UI thread, by creating it when you create the rest of your view, and setting to a variable. Or you could use a Handler that uses the UI thread and get that to run your runnable. See this link for how to set up a handler on the UI thread http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
static AnimationDrawable frameAnimation;

public boolean currentSpin = false;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //is this where you want me to do it
    ImageView coinAnima = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    coinAnima.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.coin_spin_heads);
    frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) coinAnima.getBackground();

Button bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
  bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    spinCoin1();
    }
});

}
//end of onCreate

public void spinCoin1(){  

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    frameAnimation.start();

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                      }    

                      frameAnimation.stop();

                //end of run
                }

    //starts the thread        
     }).start();

  //end of method      
  }
//end of class
}
```

And check [this](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/01/create-frame-animation-with.html) as well.

Comment: You have to add the code to implement and check value for currentSpin and spin accordingly.