# running 2 animationDrawables at the same time

Tags: android, multithreading, animationdrawable

hey everyone hope u can help n thanks 4 looking

here is my code for 2 spinning coins, but only coin1 spins....is it because they both refrence the same xml animation file or something else?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    static AnimationDrawable frameAnimation;
    static AnimationDrawable frameAnimation2;
    ImageView coinAnima2;
    ImageView coinAnima;


    public boolean currentSpin = false;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        coinAnima = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        coinAnima2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);


        Button bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
          bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            //spinCoin();

            spinCoin1();
            spinCoin2();
            }
        });

    }
    //end of onCreate

    public void spinCoin1(){
        coinAnima = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        coinAnima.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.coin_spin_heads); 

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) coinAnima.getBackground();
                                    frameAnimation.start();
                                }
                         });


                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(5000);
                              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                              }    

                              frameAnimation.stop();

                        //end of run
                        }

            //starts the thread        
             }).start();

    //end of method      
    }

    public void spinCoin2(){
        coinAnima2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        coinAnima2.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.coin_spin_heads); 

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    frameAnimation2 = (AnimationDrawable) coinAnima2.getBackground();
                                    frameAnimation2.start();
                                }
                         });


                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(5000);
                              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                              }    

                              frameAnimation2.stop();

                        //end of run
                        }

            //starts the thread        
             }).start();

    //end of method      
    }


    //end of class      
    }
```

or should i have all the code for coins 1 and 2 in coinSpin1();

any help would be appriciated

previous questions were about only 1 coin....which people have helped but why when i add a second coin and spin 2 at once (not one after the other) the second coin doesnt do anything

should i put all the code in one method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have code that I have run and tested. I would use perhaps http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html instead of Runnable, but this works. My animation file is:

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
android:id="@+id/selected"
android:oneshot="false" >
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/wheel_10"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/wheel_11"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/wheel_12"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/wheel_13"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/wheel_14"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/wheel_15"
    android:duration="50"/>
```

and java class:

```
public class Coin extends Activity {
    static AnimationDrawable frameAnimation;
    static AnimationDrawable frameAnimation2;
    ImageView coinAnima2;
    ImageView coinAnima;

    public boolean currentSpin = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.coin);
            coinAnima = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            coinAnima2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
            Button bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                spinCoin1();
           }
        });
   }

public void spinCoin1() {
    coinAnima = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    coinAnima.setBackgroundResource(R.animator.coinanim);
    coinAnima2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    coinAnima2.setBackgroundResource(R.animator.coinanim);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) coinAnima.getBackground();
                    frameAnimation.start();

                    frameAnimation2 = (AnimationDrawable) coinAnima2.getBackground();
                    frameAnimation2.start();
                }
            });

            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }

            frameAnimation.stop();
            frameAnimation2.stop();
        }
    }).start();
}
}
```

Comment: vote 1 von, awsome exactly what i was thinking...i was tossing up between having coinSpin1() and coinSpin2() or botih in coinSpin() but went with both seperate to start with....thanks to your help i put them together and now its working...if your wanna have a look at the end result goto play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=game.data thanks again mate vote 1 @von

Answer (score 0):

Both of you coinAnima get instantiated on the same view (R.id.imageView1)
Maybe coniAnima2 should get imageView2?

```
coinAnima2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
```

Comment: sorry typo, its not the issue when i copied it, i noticed it and changed it in eclipse but forgot to here....sorry everyone

Comment: You can probably instantiate the same view, but use two different variables to hold the references. 
I would place all my animation code in the same thread (in your case, the same method). I will try to give a code example later tonight, unless you've solved it by then.

Comment: @Von you have been a great help thanks mate! im still learning but thank you...dont worry atm but ill try n post my fix tomorrow...come and have a look then if you like. i thought i might be going wrong with coinSpin1() and coinspin2(). ill try putting them together and see how it runs

Comment: android:background="@drawable/coinheads" android:src="@drawable/cointails" this was the problem it has to be set to android:background not android:src. i relised this when i first got the code to run but must have missed it in the xml layout which i checked a cpl of times